# GoogleAnalytics fails to compile on Xcode 10 beta 5 due to duplicate symbol errors

Tags: ios, google-analytics, xcode10

Building a project which includes the GoogleAnalytics library on Xcode 10 beta 5 fails during linking because of duplicate symbol errors of the GoogleAnalytics library.

This isn't an issue with CocoaPods, integrating GoogleAnalytics manually also fails with the same errors. The same issue also happens to other binary-distributed libraries (CardIO, Crashlytics, Fabric). According to the linker engineers at Apple, this is not a bug, but actually a bug fixed in Xcode 10 beta 5. The fix is not interoperable with broken static libraries that were built with older Xcode prior to 10b5, and the best solution where possible is to compile those libraries with a newer version of Xcode (I had the same issue with CardIO and was successfully fixed it using just by recompiling it with Xcode 10b5).

Since GoogleAnalytics is closed source, I can’t do anything with it. Could anyone of the GoogleAnalytics maintainers recompile it with the latest Xcode and distribute a new version?

https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/106694
https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/7965
https://twitter.com/crashlytics/status/1024359450436685824
https://twitter.com/steipete/status/1024905104191901698

Error log:

```
Ld /Users/redacted/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/DuplicateSymbolError-hdngfzrxvqtekrbpcrcqnsfnwsys/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/DuplicateSymbolError.app/DuplicateSymbolError normal arm64 (in target: DuplicateSymbolError)
    cd /Users/redacted/DuplicateSymbolError
    export IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=12.0
    /Applications/Xcode-10.beta.5.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch arm64 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode-10.beta.5.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS12.0.sdk -L/Users/redacted/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/DuplicateSymbolError-hdngfzrxvqtekrbpcrcqnsfnwsys/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos -L/Users/redacted/DuplicateSymbolError/Pods/GoogleAnalytics/Libraries -F/Users/redacted/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/DuplicateSymbolError-hdngfzrxvqtekrbpcrcqnsfnwsys/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos -filelist /Users/redacted/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/DuplicateSymbolError-hdngfzrxvqtekrbpcrcqnsfnwsys/Build/Intermediates.noindex/DuplicateSymbolError.build/Debug-iphoneos/DuplicateSymbolError.build/Objects-normal/arm64/DuplicateSymbolError.LinkFileList -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @executable_path/Frameworks -miphoneos-version-min=12.0 -dead_strip -Xlinker -object_path_lto -Xlinker /Users/redacted/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/DuplicateSymbolError-hdngfzrxvqtekrbpcrcqnsfnwsys/Build/Intermediates.noindex/DuplicateSymbolError.build/Debug-iphoneos/DuplicateSymbolError.build/Objects-normal/arm64/DuplicateSymbolError_lto.o -Xlinker -export_dynamic -Xlinker -no_deduplicate -fembed-bitcode-marker -fobjc-link-runtime -L/Applications/Xcode-10.beta.5.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/iphoneos -Xlinker -add_ast_path -Xlinker /Users/redacted/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/DuplicateSymbolError-hdngfzrxvqtekrbpcrcqnsfnwsys/Build/Intermediates.noindex/DuplicateSymbolError.build/Debug-iphoneos/DuplicateSymbolError.build/Objects-normal/arm64/DuplicateSymbolError.swiftmodule -ObjC -lGoogleAnalytics -lsqlite3 -lz -framework CoreData -framework SystemConfiguration -lc++ -weak_framework CoreMedia -weak_framework AudioToolbox -weak_framework Accelerate -weak_framework AVFoundation -weak_framework MobileCoreServices -lPods-DuplicateSymbolError -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/redacted/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/DuplicateSymbolError-hdngfzrxvqtekrbpcrcqnsfnwsys/Build/Intermediates.noindex/DuplicateSymbolError.build/Debug-iphoneos/DuplicateSymbolError.build/Objects-normal/arm64/DuplicateSymbolError_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/redacted/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/DuplicateSymbolError-hdngfzrxvqtekrbpcrcqnsfnwsys/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/DuplicateSymbolError.app/DuplicateSymbolError

duplicate symbol l022 in:
    /Users/redacted/DuplicateSymbolError/Pods/GoogleAnalytics/Libraries/libGoogleAnalytics.a(GAIUtil.o)
    /Users/redacted/DuplicateSymbolError/Pods/GoogleAnalytics/Libraries/libGoogleAnalytics.a(GAIError.o)
duplicate symbol l023 in:
    /Users/redacted/DuplicateSymbolError/Pods/GoogleAnalytics/Libraries/libGoogleAnalytics.a(GAIUtil.o)
    /Users/redacted/DuplicateSymbolError/Pods/GoogleAnalytics/Libraries/libGoogleAnalytics.a(GAIError.o)
duplicate symbol l024 in:
    /Users/redacted/DuplicateSymbolError/Pods/GoogleAnalytics/Libraries/libGoogleAnalytics.a(GAIUtil.o)
    /Users/redacted/DuplicateSymbolError/Pods/GoogleAnalytics/Libraries/libGoogleAnalytics.a(GAIError.o)
duplicate symbol l066 in:
    /Users/redacted/DuplicateSymbolError/Pods/GoogleAnalytics/Libraries/libGoogleAnalytics.a(GAICoreDataUtil.o)
    /Users/redacted/DuplicateSymbolError/Pods/GoogleAnalytics/Libraries/libGoogleAnalytics.a(GAIHitUtil.o)
duplicate symbol l071 in:
    /Users/redacted/DuplicateSymbolError/Pods/GoogleAnalytics/Libraries/libGoogleAnalytics.a(GAIHitUtil.o)
    /Users/redacted/DuplicateSymbolError/Pods/GoogleAnalytics/Libraries/libGoogleAnalytics.a(GAIStringUtil.o)
duplicate symbol l160 in:
    /Users/redacted/DuplicateSymbolError/Pods/GoogleAnalytics/Libraries/libGoogleAnalytics.a(GAITrackerImpl.o)
    /Users/redacted/DuplicateSymbolError/Pods/GoogleAnalytics/Libraries/libGoogleAnalytics.a(GAITrackerModel.o)
duplicate symbol l161 in:
    /Users/redacted/DuplicateSymbolError/Pods/GoogleAnalytics/Libraries/libGoogleAnalytics.a(GAITrackerImpl.o)
    /Users/redacted/DuplicateSymbolError/Pods/GoogleAnalytics/Libraries/libGoogleAnalytics.a(GAITrackerModel.o)
duplicate symbol l162 in:
    /Users/redacted/DuplicateSymbolError/Pods/GoogleAnalytics/Libraries/libGoogleAnalytics.a(GAITrackerImpl.o)
    /Users/redacted/DuplicateSymbolError/Pods/GoogleAnalytics/Libraries/libGoogleAnalytics.a(GAITrackerModel.o)
duplicate symbol l163 in:
    /Users/redacted/DuplicateSymbolError/Pods/GoogleAnalytics/Libraries/libGoogleAnalytics.a(GAITrackerImpl.o)
    /Users/redacted/DuplicateSymbolError/Pods/GoogleAnalytics/Libraries/libGoogleAnalytics.a(GAITrackerModel.o)
duplicate symbol l036 in:
    /Users/redacted/DuplicateSymbolError/Pods/GoogleAnalytics/Libraries/libGoogleAnalytics.a(GAITrackedViewController.o)
    /Users/redacted/DuplicateSymbolError/Pods/GoogleAnalytics/Libraries/libGoogleAnalytics.a(GAIEcommercePromotion.o)
duplicate symbol l037 in:
    /Users/redacted/DuplicateSymbolError/Pods/GoogleAnalytics/Libraries/libGoogleAnalytics.a(GAITrackedViewController.o)
    /Users/redacted/DuplicateSymbolError/Pods/GoogleAnalytics/Libraries/libGoogleAnalytics.a(GAIEcommercePromotion.o)
duplicate symbol l038 in:
    /Users/redacted/DuplicateSymbolError/Pods/GoogleAnalytics/Libraries/libGoogleAnalytics.a(GAIExceptionParser.o)
    /Users/redacted/DuplicateSymbolError/Pods/GoogleAnalytics/Libraries/libGoogleAnalytics.a(GAIEcommercePromotion.o)
duplicate symbol l039 in:
    /Users/redacted/DuplicateSymbolError/Pods/GoogleAnalytics/Libraries/libGoogleAnalytics.a(GAIExceptionParser.o)
    /Users/redacted/DuplicateSymbolError/Pods/GoogleAnalytics/Libraries/libGoogleAnalytics.a(GAIEcommercePromotion.o)
duplicate symbol l129 in:
    /Users/redacted/DuplicateSymbolError/Pods/GoogleAnalytics/Libraries/libGoogleAnalytics.a(GAIDictionaryBuilder.o)
    /Users/redacted/DuplicateSymbolError/Pods/GoogleAnalytics/Libraries/libGoogleAnalytics.a(GAIUsageTracker.o)
duplicate symbol l130 in:
    /Users/redacted/DuplicateSymbolError/Pods/GoogleAnalytics/Libraries/libGoogleAnalytics.a(GAIDictionaryBuilder.o)
    /Users/redacted/DuplicateSymbolError/Pods/GoogleAnalytics/Libraries/libGoogleAnalytics.a(GAIUsageTracker.o)
duplicate symbol l151 in:
    /Users/redacted/DuplicateSymbolError/Pods/GoogleAnalytics/Libraries/libGoogleAnalytics.a(GAITrackerModel.o)
    /Users/redacted/DuplicateSymbolError/Pods/GoogleAnalytics/Libraries/libGoogleAnalytics.a(GAISqlStore.o)
duplicate symbol l152 in:
    /Users/redacted/DuplicateSymbolError/Pods/GoogleAnalytics/Libraries/libGoogleAnalytics.a(GAITrackerModel.o)
    /Users/redacted/DuplicateSymbolError/Pods/GoogleAnalytics/Libraries/libGoogleAnalytics.a(GAISqlStore.o)
duplicate symbol l153 in:
    /Users/redacted/DuplicateSymbolError/Pods/GoogleAnalytics/Libraries/libGoogleAnalytics.a(GAITrackerModel.o)
    /Users/redacted/DuplicateSymbolError/Pods/GoogleAnalytics/Libraries/libGoogleAnalytics.a(GAISqlStore.o)
duplicate symbol l154 in:
    /Users/redacted/DuplicateSymbolError/Pods/GoogleAnalytics/Libraries/libGoogleAnalytics.a(GAITrackerModel.o)
    /Users/redacted/DuplicateSymbolError/Pods/GoogleAnalytics/Libraries/libGoogleAnalytics.a(GAISqlStore.o)
duplicate symbol l155 in:
    /Users/redacted/DuplicateSymbolError/Pods/GoogleAnalytics/Libraries/libGoogleAnalytics.a(GAITrackerModel.o)
    /Users/redacted/DuplicateSymbolError/Pods/GoogleAnalytics/Libraries/libGoogleAnalytics.a(GAISqlStore.o)
duplicate symbol l156 in:
    /Users/redacted/DuplicateSymbolError/Pods/GoogleAnalytics/Libraries/libGoogleAnalytics.a(GAITrackerModel.o)
    /Users/redacted/DuplicateSymbolError/Pods/GoogleAnalytics/Libraries/libGoogleAnalytics.a(GAISqlStore.o)
duplicate symbol l157 in:
    /Users/redacted/DuplicateSymbolError/Pods/GoogleAnalytics/Libraries/libGoogleAnalytics.a(GAITrackerModel.o)
    /Users/redacted/DuplicateSymbolError/Pods/GoogleAnalytics/Libraries/libGoogleAnalytics.a(GAISqlStore.o)
duplicate symbol l158 in:
    /Users/redacted/DuplicateSymbolError/Pods/GoogleAnalytics/Libraries/libGoogleAnalytics.a(GAITrackerModel.o)
    /Users/redacted/DuplicateSymbolError/Pods/GoogleAnalytics/Libraries/libGoogleAnalytics.a(GAISqlStore.o)
duplicate symbol l159 in:
    /Users/redacted/DuplicateSymbolError/Pods/GoogleAnalytics/Libraries/libGoogleAnalytics.a(GAITrackerModel.o)
    /Users/redacted/DuplicateSymbolError/Pods/GoogleAnalytics/Libraries/libGoogleAnalytics.a(GAISqlStore.o)
ld: 24 duplicate symbols for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue myself. The Xcode 10 beta 6 (released a few days ago) fixes the issue.